# Python: list of objects vs list of integers behavior

Tags: python, list, reference

I'm new to the language and I am a bit confused about references in Python.

Consider this code:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

a = A(3)
v=[a]
print(f'obj before: v[0].x={v[0].x}')
a.x = a.x + 1
print(f'obj after:  v[0].x={v[0].x}')

b = 3
w=[b]
print(f'int before: w[0]={w[0]}')
b = b + 1
print(f'int after:  w[0]={w[0]}')
```

=====================
output:

```
obj before: v[0].x=3
obj after:  v[0].x=4
int before: w[0]=3
int after:  w[0]=3
```

Why do the obj and int versions of the code work differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a = A(3)

The variable a points to an object.

> v=[a]

The first element of v points to the same object.

> a.x = a.x + 1

Change the attribute "x" of the object.

v still contains the same object but its attribute has changed.

> b = 3

The variable b points to the object 3.

> w=[b]

The first element of w also points to the object 3.

> b = b + 1

b now points to what you get when you perform addition on the object 3 and the object 1, which is the object 4.

w still contains the object 3. You never changed any attributes of this object and you never changed where the first element of w points to.

Comment: thanks, so if I wanted v's elements unaffected then I guess I should have put a clone of a in v like this: v=[copy.deepcopy(a)]. But it doesn't look very neat to me.

Comment: Yes, or just construct the same object in the same way (`A(3)`) and put it in there. Calling a class creates a distinct new object.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this, you are modifying the object `a`:

```
a.x = a.x + 1
```

When you are doing this, you are changing what variable `b` refers to:

```
b = b + 1
```

In other words, there is a big difference between `b` and `x` in the above code: `b` is a variable and `x` is an attribute of `a`.

Assigning something to a variable does not modify any objects, and therefore affects only the variable to which the assignment was made<sup>*</sup>, whereas setting the value of an attribute modifies the object, which can be seen in any variable which references that object.

---

<sup>*</sup> There are also changes in refcounts affecting garbage collector, but is not relevant now.

Comment: thanks for your help, you effectively said the same as Denziloe